# Is there a way to "Turn Off" My Magazine on Samsung Note 3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3

I just got a new Samsung Galaxy Note 3 and it has the annoying feature of "My Magazine". I was able to unbind "My Magazine" from using Home button, however, is there a way to turn it off (like with some other apps: Settings -> Applications -> All -> {app name} -> "Turn Off")?
I have searched around the net and seems like that option is available for Galaxy S5 users, however, could not find anything for Note 3.

Comment: Unlock the bootloader root and flash cyanogenmod

Comment: This method is a little complicated but will work..
(FYI I haven't used Samsung in years..) You'll have to find the name of the package.. and then follow [THESE](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/disable-system-app-android/) steps..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but in case you're still annoyed by My Magazine, the Android 5.0 Lollipop update allows you to completely disable the app (not uninstall it, but it's still a huge improvement.)

Answer (score 0):

The "My Magazine" feature is integrated into the Touchwiz launcher, so there's really no way to completely turn it off under Jelly Bean.  If you freeze/disable the app you'll see frequent crashes.

If you're still under Jelly Bean, you unfortunately cannot do what Robert suggests because it only applies to Lollipop.  However, the simple way to get rid of this piece of crap is to simply install say the NOVA launcher, or any other available in Google Play.